# Como "transformar" um commit específico em um branch?

Tags: git, commit

Gostaria de pegar um `commit` anterior específico e transformá-lo em um brancho.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso no `Git`?

Answer (score 8):

Basta passar o commit ID na hora de criar o branch:

```
git checkout -b BRANCH_NAME COMMIT_ID
```

**Exemplo**

```
git checkout -b teste 5d6b8da2f0e32a100087eecb73fc2dd47579748f
```

Com isso, um novo branch "teste" será criado baseado no commit:
5d6b8da2f0e32a100087eecb73fc2dd47579748f

Answer (score 3):

Para ver o histórico de commits, digite:

```
git log
```

Após isso basta pegar o ID do commit que deseja:

```
git commit -b nomebranch 7e85bcb18b1fcf58738f3ec6a2e04171975ef442
```

Ou:

```
git checkout 7e85bcb18b1fcf58738f3ec6a2e04171975ef442
git checkout -b nomebranch
```